# How to 'fillToValue' in Jqplot when we have null values for some x-axis ticks

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, charts, jqplot

I am trying to use `fillToValue` property for jQplot series to fill that series to a particular value.

I am using this function to create an array of series:

```
/**
 * This function populates the graphSeries array to contain the different properties of each series.
 *
 * @param {string} Yaxis: which Y axis to use(yaxis or y2axis)
 * @param {string} Color: Color code for the graph line
 * @param {string} MarkerColor: Color of the marker for each point on the graph
 * @param {string} Style: Shape of the marker(star, diamond, etc)
 * @param {string} Label: Text value of the series, which would appear on the legend also.
 */ 
    function seriesCreation(Yaxis, Color, MarkerColor, Style, Label, Show){

        graphSeries.push({
            yaxis : Yaxis,
            shadow : true,
            shadowAngle: 45,
            shadowOffset : 2.25,
            color : Color,
            label : Label,
            breakOnNull : true,
            markerOptions: {
                show: true,
                size: 12.0,
                color: MarkerColor,
                style: Style
            },
            show: true,
            fill: Show,
            fillToZero : true,
            fillToValue : 1
        });
    }
```

This works fine if i have an array of values without any `null` values in them, but if i have array with `null` values then its doesn't fill with color nor draws the line.

Example: chartData1 works fine but chartData2 doesn't work(doesn't fills up with color nor the lines shows up)

```
var chartData1 = [["19-Jan-2012", 2.61], ["20-Jan-2012", 5.00], ["21-Jan-2012", 6.00], ["22-Jan-2012", 3.00], ["23-Jan-2012", 8.00], ["24-Jan-2012", 1.00]];

var chartData2 = [["19-Jan-2012", null], ["20-Jan-2012", null], ["21-Jan-2012", 6.00], ["22-Jan-2012", 3.00], ["23-Jan-2012", 8.00], ["24-Jan-2012", null]];
```

Does anyone knows how to do this?? I think this concept may be of use to a lot people using `jqplot`.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a pre-processing before plotting your chart in which you modify each value equals to "null" to an integer value : "0".

Comment: If the do that, then it will produce a line touching 0 on y-axis, 'null' helps me to not draw a line,  so that i only get a line when there is a actual number and at null, its blank.

Comment: I think in order to be able to fill space between two lines, jqplot needs same number of points on each line. With your "null" values chartData1 has more points than chartData2. But I'm maybe wrong

Comment: Value 0 is very different from null. A line that discontinues, does usually mean that you have no value to place there. @AnthonyLeGovic I think you point to the right direction. In chats with multiple series, one is allowed to have NULL values and is still rendered correctly. Maybe adding a second, hidden dummy-series is a workaround.